# html5 canvas lag

Tags: html, canvas, lag

I'm making tetris on a canvas.  it works fine for the first piece and somtimes the 2nd and 3rd.  but it soon starts lagging and it just gets worse.  It doesn't seem like this is too many object to slow it down.  I was thinking it might be because I'm painting the whole board everytime it moves, but even that doesn't seem to be a big deal (not like it painting alot of stuff).   my project is at http://tetris.townsendwebdd.com.  any help would be really nice.  I'm kinda stuck until I fix this
thank you

Comment: please note, the image is a different canvas

Comment: I took a look in your code. I can't find the cause of your problem but I'm sure is not the number of pieces: if you press _down_ and then _left_ and _right_ alternatively (without touching the borders) then it still works fast; but if you keep pressing just _left_ (hitting a border) then with every keypress it becomes slower. If you open the javascript console you'll see the error log in the `canMove` function (at `bs = this.squares[sq + this.curX + lat][(this.curY + y + vert)];` in _board.js_). You should check the _x_ and _y_ before trying to get the square.

Comment: hmm.  I have that line in a try catch because the square might be undefined.  you think that might be it?

Comment: I'm not sure, but that may be causing a memory leak somewhere. You can check if `sq+thiscurX+lat` is inside the board (same with Y) and then try to get the square.

Comment: well, I had that in a few spots.  I've removed the try catches and just pre-checked the x and y locations.  this has sped up the game, but I still run into the same problem after a few pieces.  and you right, it's mostly when I hold the btn down. 

what exactly is a memory leak?

Comment: maybe it is the double painting for every piece move?  I don't know, I'm just guessing at this point

Comment: Well your code is a little longer and I can't find where are you painting the pieces twice, but if you can paint them once then do it (but I don't think that will fix this specific problem). A [memory leak](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak) occurs when you create an object and somehow you get to a situation where the variable that represents that object doesn't exists any more, but the object is still in memory and the garbage collector is unable to remove it. More examples [here](http://javascript.info/tutorial/memory-leaks)

Comment: Good! now is working fast :)

Answer (score 0):

thank you for the help.  I think that was part of the problem.  I think the other part was that I was painting the whole board several times.  I've cleaned that up and it seems to working just fine now
thank you